# Parse Javascript - Adding user error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I created a factory in angularJS to store data to Parse User object. Every time I click to process the details and open an account for the user, it shows the following error in console:

> Failed to load resource: https://api.parse.com/1/users the server
>   responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

I checked if the service parameter is valid with attributes content, and yes it has content (not empty). This is the service body:

```
.factory('CreateUserService', function() {
    return {
      createAccount: function(user) {
          console.log("Service User: " + user.name);
          var parseUser = new Parse.User();
          parseUser.set("username", user.username);
          parseUser.set("email", user.username);
          parseUser.set("name", user.username);
          parseUser.set("password", user.username);
          parseUser.set("mobile", user.username);

          /*Attempt to create user in DB*/
          parseUser.signUp(null, {
            success: function(parseUser) {
              // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
              //alert("success!");
              return 1;
            },
            error: function(parseUser, error) {
              // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
              //alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
              return error;
            }
          });
      }
    }
});
```

I added the Parse CDN in the index.html of my application with:

```
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.7.min.js"></script>
```

Update: In Parse API Guide, this is the body of the signup:

```
user.signUp(null, {
  success: function(user) {
    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

The user object in Parse (I review through the browser) is not showing any changes to the rows number hence user not added. Any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks

Update: When I deleted the existing empty user object in Parse and ran the code, it worked and created a user Object with all columns specified in the code. Then if I try to add another user, I get a POST error. There must be a way around this since signup method by parse surely considered adding multiple users to the User object.

Comment: Why are you passing `null` on the signUp() function? Shouldn't you pass a user instead?

Comment: @mhx oops overlooked that by mistake...changed it to parseUser so now error disappears but nothing is in the database. Any ideas?

Comment: @mhx actually in the API of parse it shows null. Check my updated question with snippet from Parse Guide